# SQL first entry not adding to database

Tags: php, sql

Could someone please help with the code below. I am trying to create a registration query, however when it is submitted, I get an error for the following line:

```
$insert_query = "insert into members (First_name, last_name, Address_1, Address_2, Postcode, Email, Membership_Number, Password) values('$fname','$lname','$address1','$address2','$postcode','$email','$member','$password')";
```

This is only affecting the first_name, as the other field names are successfully submitted.

Your help would be much appreciated!!

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$select_db = mysql_select_db("thistlehc",$con);
if(isset($_POST['register']))

 $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
 $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
 $address1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address1']);
 $address2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address2']);
 $postcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']);
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $member = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['member']);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

 $query = "select membership_number from members where membership_number='$member'";
 $link = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
     $num = mysql_num_rows($link);

     if ($num>0){
      echo 'Membership Number already exists'; //Membership number already taken
     }

     else {
     $insert_query = "insert into members (First_name, last_name, Address_1, Address_2, Postcode, Email, Membership_Number, Password) values('$fname','$lname','$address1','$address2','$postcode','$email','$member','$password')";
     $result = mysql_query($insert_query)or die(mysql_error());
     echo "Registered Successfully!";
     }

?>
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Could you add it to your post?

Comment: 'Notice: Undefined variable: fname in Send_user_details.php on line 24'

which is the line shown above

Comment: your $fname become null type so in mysql it become blank value

Comment: This is the problem with using if(condition) newline action - it's easy for new developers not to understands that that if ends after that second line. Always same line or curly braces!

Answer (score 2):

Look's to me like you forgot to encapsulate the contents of your `if` statement.

```
if(isset($_POST['register']))
```

Because it doesn't have curly brackets around the code to be executed, only the first line immediately after is executed. In your case, the `if` statement seemingly returned false, and the line defining `$fname` was **not** executed, hence an undefined variable.

You want to use something similar to this -

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
 $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
 $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
 $address1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address1']);
 ...
}
```